# CentOS 7 is starting >70000 processes after startup

Tags: operating-system, centos

we have two identical  (hardware-wise) workstations running CentOS 7. On one of the machines (the "bad" one), we observe lags and it's generally less responsive:
After rebooting both machines, both machines showed no difference in cpu/memory load, but the latest PID (by checking ps -A) is extremely different. The "good" machine has a PID around 6.000, whereas the "bad" machine is above 70.000. I checked the "bad" machine directly after startup with ps -A and top, and "dracut" and possible related processes (gzip, xy) pops up a couple of hundred times.

What I think is, that on the "bad" machine some configuration is wrong, leading to the startup of these subprocesses, which resulted in an overall less responsive system.

My questions now:

1. How can I precisely log the startup on the machines?
2. How to solve eventually the issue?

And if this is dracut related, how can I check the dracut configurations and compare them between both machines?

Thank you very much.

christian

Comment: Do you have `debug` in your kernel boot parameters? Also, be sure to not have `quiet` in the parameters. You'll get less bootup output. You can check `dmesg`, `/var/log/messages` and `journalctl` for your boot logs.

Comment: How do I check the kernel boot parameters? I will check and compare dmesg (2377 lines) and /var/log/messages (8229 lines) with the functional device. Thank you already. And are these logs cleaned after rebooting or are these continuous logs?

Comment: Your `grub.cfg` file, probably in `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` in Centos has a couple `menuentry`s, find your OS version, then find the line that says something like `linux16 /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64`. On that same line, right after the `.x86_64` filename are the boot parameters. You can just add `debug` like this: `linux16 /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64 <existing_boot_parameters> debug`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found a major difference between both machines. I compared the first 6 minutes after rebooting in journalctl and the "good" machine has 147 lines containing "dracut", whereas the bad machine has 11315 lines containing "dracut". I am new here, should I alter my initial question or open a new thread?

Comment: You're welcome. I would open a new dracut specific question.

Comment: I didn't see your edit earlier about whether the logs are cleaned after rebooting. I think most of them are independent of reboots, but are dependent on size like a ring buffer (i.e. only remove the oldest log if the buffer is full). You could always make a private copy of them yourself with `cat /var/log/messages > out1`, `journalctl > out2` `dmesg > out3`. Then you won't have to worry about losing the important info.